# Two WHERE conditions in a mysql Delete query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I've got a query that deletes a row from a MySQL table that works perfectly fine if the query is as follows:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 1"
```

But it doesn't work, or give an error, when I add a `AND` clause:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 1 AND name='Jack'"
```

Doesn't MySQL `DELETE` support the `AND` clause?

Comment: This should work, if there's a row that matches your conditions. What's the error you get?

Comment: `DELETE` works fine with multiple conditions. If it's not generating an error, then chances are there isn't a row in `table` where `id` is 1 and `name` is exactly `Jack`.

Comment: how are you handling errors?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What is the *exact* error you get?  are you sure a row that matches `id = 1 AND name='Jack'` exists?

Comment: I got it working, there no error at all but I put single quotes around the id too and it fixed it. Thank for all your replies.

Comment: Around the `id` value? Have you got the id column set to a string type? That sounds.... wrong, unless you're specifically after string identifiers for some reason.

Comment: Put the real code on the question.

Comment: Before do a DELETE, try a SELECT for checking your table and query.

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't MySQL DELETE support the AND clause?

It does.